# for loop with concatenated input in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have following shellscript for a loop.

```
 $ for machine_id in `cat id_list`; do app.sh $machine_id ; done
```

I would like to do this natively with Ansible, without using shell.

The tricky part is the concatination part, currently I am using shell module to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways without using the shell.

Using `loop` :

```
   script: app.sh "{{ item }}"
   loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'file.txt').splitlines() }}"
```

Using `with_lines` :

```
   script: app.sh "{{ item }}"
   with_lines:
      - cat file.txt
```

Ansible [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. Not tested one.

```
vars:
 machine_id: 
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- name: test
  script: '/path/to/file/app.sh "{{item}}"'
  with_items: {{machine_id}}
```